# htaccess not working on EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I am having an Amazon **EC2 Instance**, I have enable the mod_rewrite but htacess not working.

Also while changing /etc/apache2/sites-available/default setting **AllowOverride none** to **AllowOverride All** it is giving me internal server error.

Am I missing something.

Comment: have you restarted the server ? `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

Comment: What does your error logs say when you tried changing `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: Log Says : /var/www/.htaccess: Invalid Command '<option', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not include in the server configuration

Answer (score 1):

```
 internal server error.
```

Means there is something wrong with the `.htaccess` file likely

Check `/var/log/httpd/error.log` it may give you the line. but it will tell you whats wrong

Comment: no you don't get me, it is not taking htaccess even I have placed a wrong htaccess. It is showing error only when I change Allowoverride none to Allowoverride all

Comment: it IS taking the .htaccess, It has a synatx error. Leave Alloverride all and delete the file, See if it works

Comment: In this file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default?

Comment: yeah where ever you changed it before, There of httd.conf should be fine. Check the error log mentioned though

Comment: the httd.conf file is empty

Comment: sorry mis spelling httpd.conf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41031/discussion-between-sourabh-kasliwal-and-user1281385)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I try and that work for me

1. Open file as

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

2. Second

remove comment sign (#)
`AccessFileName .htaccess`

3. Then find the line where there is

   `<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride`**None**
        `Require all granted
   </Directory>`

   replace "None" with "All"
   `AllowOverride All`

I found this on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu/61022#61022

Answer (score 0):

Suppose It's showing some Internal Server Error First, you activate **ModRewrite** feature:

```dart
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```